# Longest list of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I prove that if $dim(V) = n$, the longest list of linearly independent vectors in $V$ has length $n$?

I know this seems obvious, but I am having trouble constructing the proof of this statement.

Answer (score 3):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma. By the way, in my opinion this fact isn't really that obvious at all; in fact if we weaken the vector space axioms in various (seemingly minor) ways it's no longer true.

---

Although it's worth mentioning an important generalization of vector spaces where exchange *does* remain true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid.

Answer (score 0):

We see that by the definition of dimension, $dim(V)$ is the cardinality of
a basis of $V$. A basis is a set of vectors that span a given vector space
and our linearly independent. Fixing $dim(V) = n$, we know that if we have
a basis of vectors that is of cardinality greater than $n$, this would
contradict the definition of $dim(V)$. A similar argument can be made for why
this basis cannot be of cardinality less than $n$.